# An example of a beginner-level Algorithm, intermediate level Algorithm and a complex/expert level Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I'd like to get a sense for the range of complexity that Algorithms fall into.  I think it would be interesting and helpful for those, like me, trying to better understand how algorithms are formulated and how to deconstruct them.

Can you offer a basic algorithm with explanation, an intermediate algorithm with explanation, and maybe an expert level one (with or without) an explanation?

Comment: I believe this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Alexander: it's undecidable.

Comment: Everything is relative, other than the fact that this question is subjective and argumentative. ;-)

Comment: Meh, it's a perfectly reasonable question for a beginner to ask.

Comment: @Legatou So what would be a perfectly reasonable question for an intermediate/advanced user to ask? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow me to refer you to this website for happy brainmunching. http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems

**Beginner Algorithm**: *Find the first element of a sequence that matches a criterion*. This is a simple O(n) traversal of, say, a list or array, search for the first truth case it sees and returns the result or index position.

**Beginner-Intermediate Algorithm**: *Define an in-place Heap Sort that requires O(1) memory*. This requires playing with memory and enough abstract thinking to break you out of the diapers of computational science.

**Intermediate Algorithm**: *Find the 1,000,000th prime number within 5 seconds of computation time.* This is a simple math problem that most programmers should be able to solve in a day, if they consider themselves at all acquainted with computation science.

**Intermediate-Advanced Algorithm**: *Define a genetic algorithm.* Not much to say here, just Wikipedia it.

**Advanced Algorithm**: *Define a quantum annealing sort function that finishes in O(n) time.* You can earn your Ph.D with this one. I mention something like this that is damn near impossible with a Turing-complete digital computation system because it's in places like this that computation science is treading new ground. Anyone that's advanced in computer science and algorithmic study is concerned with strange ground like this.

Comment: Kind of a leap from "Beginner" to "Beginner-Intermediate" there!  My guess is that around 30% of working programmers have *heard of* a heap data structure.  (Also genetic algorithms aren't hard -- that would be a better choice for "Intermediate".)

Comment: 30% of working programmers maybe, but 100% of CS grads should have heard of it. The original question isn't really clear as to whether it's asking for algorithm examples from a CS perspective or a working programmer perspective.

Comment: Yeah, you guys come up with great criticism. I did my best to give him an idea of computation science algorithms. I'd edit and expand if the question weren't closed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember of my algorithms college course, we first started with various sorts, like [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), then we learned [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)